# The code below only detect the laptop webcam but doesn't detect the HIKVISION camera concted via USB3.0 I'm using anaconda spyder with pythone 3.7

Tags: python, spyder, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture (1)
#cams_test = 100
#for i in range(0, cams_test):
 #   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
  #  test, frame = cap.read()
   # print("i : "+str(i)+" /// result: "+str(test))

while True:
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()
    ret1, frame1 = video_capture_1.read()

    if (ret0):
        cv2.imshow('cam0', frame0)

    if (ret1):
        cv2.imshow('cam1', frame1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord ('q'):
        break

video_capture_0.release()
video_capture_1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the code here is a cv2 videocapture and videorelase function they work fine with the webcam but doesn't not work with a 2nd camera
The issue is that only one windows show instead of 2. the one that show is the one using my webcam(0) the other one the usb camera(1) doesn't show up

Comment: what is the problem? are you getting an error? is it not working as expected? can you post the result?

Comment: @AlmogAtNailo the result is 1 windows with the webcam and the second windows that need to out put the usb camera doesn't show up